# Observer pattern-observable is not present beforehand while initialising the observer

Tags: design-patterns, observer-pattern

Is there any alternative or other way of implementing observer pattern to handle the case when observable is not present beforehand while initialising the observer.
I want to make an object observer at later stage when observable object is created.

Comment: what is reason of this?

Answer (score 0):

as I understood: you want to generate the object to be observed at a later time, while the observers for this object were already generated.
If that is the case you probably need an object in the middle.

How about declaring a new class such as "Publisher" and instantiating an object from it that has a list of observers. The observers can add themselves to the list, even if your observable has not been created yet.
When you later create an observable, you can assign the publisher to your observable as a property.

So what you could do is the following:

1. create a new object of class "Publisher" that has a list of observers.
2. the observers should already register themselves to the list.
3. in your Observable class you need the property of the new class "Publisher" (or directly the list), which you assign later, when you create the object of the Observable.

let me know if it worked out.
otherwise please post a code.
kind regards.